# how to display variable value in alert box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wanted to display variable value in alert box.

please see below code :

```
<script>
    function check() {
        var content = document.getElementById("one").value;
        alert(content);
    }
</script>
<body onload="check()">
    <div style="position: absolute; z-index: 9; width: 450px; top: 38px; margin-left: 176px;">
        <style>
            div#layout {
                margin:0px;
                padding:px;
                width:450px;
                margin:0px auto;
                overflow:hidden;
            }
        </style>
        <div id="layout">
             <span id="one" style="display:none" ph="layout1" class="ione">yes</span>    
             <span id="two" style="display:none" ph="layout1" class="ione">no</span>    
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

When i am executing this code then it is showing value as undefined in alert box.
value in span id"one"is changing in different different situation.
i want to track every time...so i cant hardcode it.

can you please help in this?

Answer (score 8):

spans not have the value in html

one is the `id` for `span` tag

in javascript use

```
document.getElementById('one').innerText;
```

in jQuery use

```
$('#one').text()

function check() {
    var content = document.getElementById("one").innerText;
    alert(content);
}
```

or

```
function check() {
        var content = $('#one').text();
        alert(content);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//    alert("test");
$("#name").click(function(){
var content = document.getElementById("ghufran").innerHTML ;
   alert(content);
  });

 //var content = $('#one').text();

})
```

there u go buddy this code actually works

Comment: In general, try to provide an explanation for what your code does.

Comment: `var setScript = "<script>alert('test');<//script>";` doesn't work for me

Comment: what happen to this user? this is nice answer

Answer (score 1):

Try innerText property:

```
var content = document.getElementById("one").innerText;
alert(content);
```

See also this fiddle http://fiddle.jshell.net/4g8vb/

Answer (score 1):

Clean way with no jQuery:

```
function check(some_id) {
    var content = document.getElementById(some_id).childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    alert(content);
}
```

This is assuming each span has only the value as a child and no embedded HTML.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('one').innerText;
alert(content);
```

It does not print the value;
But, if done this way

```
document.getElementById('one').value;
alert(content);
```